# How do I extend my query to join the result with another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables. I am making a query on one table, and would like to join the result with a second table to get the final result.

My tables are:

```
create table table1 (col1 int, col2 int)
create table table2 (col3 int, col4 int)

insert into table1 values
(1, NULL), (2,10), (3, 20)

insert into table2 values
(1,100),(2,200),(3,300)
```

The query

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
```

gives me

```
col1
2
3
```

How do I extend my query to receive the result as follows:

```
col1    col4
2        200   
3        300
```

I put this example on SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e89e/1 to quickly test queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.col1,t2.col4
FROM table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on
t1.col1 = t2.col3
WHERE t1.col2 IS NOT NULL
```

You need to join the tables as per your expected output.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9489f/2)